# How to exchange variables between HTML using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I have 2 html page and javascript. i want x variable in page2 to show on page1.

Page2.html

```
var x =1;
```

Page1.html

```
<input type="Button" id="text2" value="click" onclick=show()/>
```

And Data.js

```
var LocalStorage.Score = x;

function show();
{
    alert(LocalStorage.Score);
}
```

Comment: Is this happening on the same website? If you go from page1 to page2, then you shouldn't loose the value of 'x' variable.

Comment: Try using Cookies or localstorage (HTML 5 only)

Comment: Are the pages shown simultanious, or in sequence? If in sequence just use a URL parameter when going to page2 from page1?

Comment: pages are shown simultanious, i don't want to send variable and change to other page straight away.

Answer (score 0):

You can use between the two to exchange the variables between two HTML pages.

- Cookies
- Querystring

For example:

```
<a href='page1.html?x=1'>First link</a>
<a href='page2.html?y=2'>Second link</a>
```

Then using querystring try like this:

```
var querystr = new Querystring();
var v = querystr.get("x");
```

Also check [HTML5 local storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)

Answer (score 0):

you could write code like this in your `Data.js` file.

```
localStorage.setItem("score", x); //x-variable,setting values in localstorage;

var foo = localStorage.getItem("score"); //Get values from localstorage.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cookies for this:

```
document.cookie="score="+x; // this will create the cookie

// Other HTML page, you will use getCookie("score")
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) != -1) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}

var score = getCookie("score");
console.log(score);
```

but I do not recommend this because there are softwares that can edit cookies on browsers.